# prevent closing bootbox by escape button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I have this function -

```
function startReview(response_message, prompt, model, reviewable_id, reviewable_type, user_id) {
    bootbox.hideAll();
    if (response_message && response_message.length > 0) {
        response_message = response_message.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
        var message = response_message
        message += '...';
        var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
            message: message,
            closeButton: false,
            buttons: {
                thumbs_up: {
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>',
                    className: 'btn-success',
                    callback: function () {
                        saveUserFeedback(true, prompt, response_message, model, reviewable_id, reviewable_type, user_id);
                        dialog.modal('hide');
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                thumbs_down: {
                    label: '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>',
                    className: 'btn-danger',
                    callback: function () {
                        saveUserFeedback(false, prompt, response_message, model, reviewable_id, reviewable_type, user_id);
                        dialog.modal('hide');
                        return false;
                    }
                },
            },
        });
        $('.bootbox .btn-success, .bootbox .btn-danger').parent().css('text-align', 'center');
    } else {
        bootbox.alert("...");
    }
}
```

The user gets a thumbs up and down buttons that has a callback by pressing one of them. I want the user to be unable to close the bootbox by 'esc' button. I tried these -

```
$(document).on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', function (e) {
    debugger
    if (e.which == 27) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

tried to add this below the dialog declaration -

```
dialog.init(function () {
    dialog.find('.modal-content').on('keydown.dismiss.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 27) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

tried to add onEscape: null

none of them worked.
if i add a debugger inside the if (e.which == 27) block, the debugger stops and when I allow the code to run it looks like it is preventing the bootbox from closing.
Without debugging, it doesn't seem to work.
When I run the code on the console, it prevents it from closing the window.

Any ideas why is this happening or what else can I check?

Comment: Did you try the `onEscape` option? https://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#option-onEscape

Comment: Yes. didn't solve it

Comment: Can you add a snippet (with all required CDN js / css includes) so we can see the / attempt a fix for you?

Comment: The `alert()` function overrides the user-provided `onEscape` but the `.dialog()` method honours the onEscape feature.  If it's not working for you, then please update the question with what you have tried (what you have tried when using onEscape).  Here's a fiddle showing onEscape with dialog() : https://jsfiddle.net/m076cqr2/

Comment: here is the file in the code, i added some dummy data - 
https://www.coderstool.com/cs/aKT4jN

i tried to remove the alert function but it allowed me to escape. i used onescape - 
        var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
            message: message,
            closeButton: false,
            onEscape: false,  
            buttons: {
...
didn't solve it

Comment: I'm using ruby on rails, in my controller i have a function that calls a js file as a response - this file contains the function above. it is creating a bootbox